# xml to datatable

Tags: c#, xml

can i load data from xml to data table?i don't want to use loop anymore.
now i develop in c#.net 2008.my xml format may be like below.

```
<ItemCode>001</ItemCode>
<ItemName>Item001</ItemName>
<Qty>50</Qty>
<Price>100</Price>
<Amt>5000</Amt>
<ItemCode>002</ItemCode>
<ItemName>Item002</ItemName>
<Qty>70</Qty>
<Price>100</Price>
<Amt>7000</Amt> 
<ItemCode>003</ItemCode>
<ItemName>Item003</ItemName>
<Qty>90</Qty>
<Price>100</Price>
<Amt>9000</Amt>
```

Regards
Han

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You should look at `DataTable.ReadXML`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfxbc3by%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: And you can use a Dataset and call it's ReadXml() method to load a XML file that contains multiple tables and rows! :-)

Comment: hi friends,my xml format is like this.it occurs error when i read this xml.i think it only accept with built in xml format.i mean we must need to use write.xml from table before read.xml.is it correct?mine is customized xml format.how i do?

Comment: No, you use DataTable.ReadXML to load your data table with XML,just as the link I provided shows. I'm assuming the XML you're showing is just a snippet from your document, as it has no root node. We can't help further without a much better description of your error and your code. You should also consider accepting correct answers, it's how the site works.